# Adding onto a map field of a specific document (Flutter Firestore)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `flutter` firestore and want to only add users(using the userInfo map) (and not add any other fields)  to a specific document in my PrayerRooms Collection.I am unsure of how to do this and whether this is possible [The database I want to add into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6i0c.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have other fields and you just want to add data to the `userInfo` map while keep the other fields, then you can use `updateData()`:

```
 Firestore.instance.collection("PrayersRoom").document(userId).updateData({
                     "userInfo.userId" : userId,
                     "userInfo.userCount" : 2
                   });
```

Comment: That just updates the data, I want to add more users to the userInfo not update it.

Comment: U want to add more users to the map userinfo? If you want to add more users to map in firestore, you still need to u use `updateData`

Comment: Could the reason it is not adding be that I am adding duplicates to the map? Because I kept inserting the same value.

Comment: If you are inserting the same value and to the same field using updateData then ofcourse it won't work. If you want to add different data instead of using map just do another document

Comment: please ask a different question and add the code u are using and a screenshot of the database and specify what you want exactly